# MapReduce programming system in java-actionscript

Tags: java, javascript, actionscript-3, mapreduce

Just finished reading ch23 in the excellent 'Beautiful Code' http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596510046

on Distributed Programming with MapReduce. I understand that MapReduce is a programming system designed for large-scale data processing problems, but I have a hard time getting my head around the basic examples given and how I might apply them in real world situations.

Can someone give a simple example of MapReduce implemented using either java, javascript or actionscript?

Answer (score 0):

For further information on MapReduce i would recommend you spend some time on the following topics:

- Apache Hadoop
- MongoDB mapreduce features
- Patterns For Cloud Computing

You can experiment with MongoDB for starters (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce)

Answer (score 0):

[GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com) is another MapReduce framework for Java which I find a lot easier to grasp than Hadoop.

Have a look at the examples in
http://www.gridgainsystems.com/wiki/display/GG15UG/Examples+Gallery